# How to manually set the range of coefficients on sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, mlr

I am trying to fit a regression equation of the following type in sklearn

y=ax+bx^2+cx^3+dx^5.......

I have a condition on the range of a i.e a should be between amin and amax. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are your constraints to ensure all coefficients are positive? Because if yes, passing `positive = True` to `sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression` will do. If not, the answer to this SO post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48831113/13095028) might help you

Comment: no, I do not have a constraint that a should not be negative. I just want its value to lie within a certain range.

Comment: In that case, there might not be an easy solution using sklearn. The SO post I linked refers to an answer that requires setting up linear regression manually and using a solver that supports setting constraints

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this using sklearn (that I am aware of).

[sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html) only allows non-negative least squares by specifying `positive=True` in the `LinearModel` constructor. Under the hood [scipy.optimize.nnls](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html) is used for this.

However, the constraint linear regression model you want can be estimated using
[scipy.optimize.lsq_linear](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.lsq_linear.html#scipy.optimize.lsq_linear).